# Get multiple items in one session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing multiple items into one session variable: which is 4 different words.

I need to be able to take those 4 different wordsin the one session, and store them into separate variables so i can use them, is this possible? and if so how?

_application just holds text from a series of text from text boxes.

Here is my session class.

```
 public class JobApplicantSession
{

    public JobApplication ApplicationSession
    {

      get {if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] != null)
               return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
           return null; }

      set{ HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = value; }
    }
```

Job application: Job application holds information from a list of textboxes thats it.

```
JobApplication _application;
_application = new JobApplication(jobID);
if (i < _applicant.Fields.Count)
                _applicant.AddAnswer((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
            else
                _application.AddAnswer((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
```

add to the session:

```
_sessions.ApplicationSession = _application;
```

I can get the session:

```
JobApplication application;
var jas = new JobApplicantSession();
application = jas.ApplicationSession;
```

Job application:

```
public class JobApplication
{
    private int _jobID = -1;
    public JobApplication(int jobID)
    {
        _jobID = jobID;
    }
    List<String> _answers = new List<String>();
    List<JobApplicationField> _fields = new List<JobApplicationField>();
    public List<JobApplicationField> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
    }
    public int JobID()
    {
        return _jobID;
    }
    public List<String> Answers
    {
        get { return _answers; }
        set { _answers = value; }
    }
    public void AddAnswer(String answer)
    {
        _answers.Add(answer);
    }
    public void AddField(JobApplicationField field)
    {
        if (field.HasFieldID)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _fields.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (_fields[i].FieldID == field.FieldID)
                {
                    _fields[i] = field;
                    return;
                }
            }

        }

        _fields.Add(field);
    }
    public void PopulateFromDatabase()
    {
        JobPositionSystemDAL dal = new JobPositionSystemDAL();
        DataSet data = dal.OpenJobOpeningByID(_jobID);
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            JobApplicationField field = new JobApplicationField(Convert.ToInt32(row["QUESTIONID"]), row["QUESTIONTEXT"].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(row["HASCORRECTANSWER"]), row["CORRECTANSWER"].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(row["ISREQUIRED"]));
            AddField(field);
        }
    }
    public bool Verify()
    {
        if (_fields.Count != Answers.Count)
            throw new Exception("Number of answers != number of fields");
        for (int i = 0; i < _fields.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_fields[i].HasCorrectAnswer == true && _fields[i].CorrectAnswer != _answers[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        JobPositionSystemDAL database = new JobPositionSystemDAL();

        foreach(JobApplicationField field in _fields)
        {
            field.Save(_jobID, ref database);
        }

        //reload to get the Field/question ID for any new fields
        Reload();
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        _fields = new List<JobApplicationField>();
        Load(_jobID);
    }

    public void Load(int jobID)
    {
        _jobID = jobID;
        DataSet ds = DB.OpenJobOpeningByID(jobID);
        DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            int questionID = 0;
            object obj = row["QUESTIONID"];
            Int32.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out questionID);
            //int jobApplicationID = Int32.Parse(row["JOBAPPLICATIONID"] as String);
            string questionText = row["QUESTIONTEXT"] as String;
            int type = Int32.Parse(row["TYPEID"].ToString());
            bool hasCorrectAnswer = (row["HASCORRECTANSWER"] as String == "0") ? false : true;
            string correctAnswer = row["CORRECTANSWER"] as String;
            bool required = ((row["ISREQUIRED"] as String) == "0") ? false : true;

            JobApplicationField field = new JobApplicationField(questionID, questionText, hasCorrectAnswer, correctAnswer, required);
            AddField(field);
        }
    }
    private JobPositionSystemDAL _db;
    private JobPositionSystemDAL DB 
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _db)
                _db = new JobPositionSystemDAL();
            return _db;
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can i loop through and store each item into its own variable?
i will need 4 variables.

Comment: Please show the definition of `JobApplication`

Comment: please see the updated version

Comment: You still aren't showing the definition of `JobApplication`.  I'm referring to the class definition, not the variable definition.

Comment: I think i added what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it is what you are asking. If you want to store array of objects in session state you can either sotre array directly:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["data"] = new int[32];
```

or dynamically create names based on element index (strange, but possible):

```
 var data = new int[3];
 HttpContext.Current.Session["data" + 0.ToString()] = data[0]; 
 HttpContext.Current.Session["data"  + 1.ToString()] = data[1]; 
 HttpContext.Current.Session["data"  + 2.ToString()] = data[2];
```

Read in reverse order:

```
var dataArray = (int[])(HttpContext.Current.Session["data"]);
```

or

```
 var data = new int[3];
 data[0] = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["data" + + 0.ToString()];
```

Comment: i like how you are doing it dynamically but how could i use my session class?

Comment: It is **your** class - so consider figuring out yourself. Your sample is way too long for anyone to look at it - and it is not clear what you don't know. So please try to look through your question and see if you already know all parts of answer, if you find something still missing - refine question and ask again. Consider reading http://sscce.org/ for better questions.